# How to send small picture as a text message in android

Tags: android

I have develop sms app in android that will send message to particular number using Sms manager API.
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();    smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
Now i want that my app will send small picture as a text message, who will i can do this?

Comment: Whats stopping you from sending some common ones like `":-)"` , `";-)"` , `":-D"` ?

Answer (score 0):

there are four things I would like to suggest you

1. Simple emoji like :-) , ;-) etc must get rendered by the default sms application itself. So they might not support in your application as you haven't coded for it but for other applications it will.
2. Use font-awesome. This is a quick and easy library which provides you numerous icons and also using it is very simple. For that refer [this link.](https://github.com/liltof/font-awsome-for-android)
3. Use the iconify library. It is kind of similar as font- awesome. Refer [here](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify) for the same.
4. You can use apache's language library. through which you can convert unicode character to there equivalent symbol. A unicode character is a "\u" followed 4-digit string. For example \u2764 represents a ❤ (heart).

For this insert your character in the string like this.

```
String str = "Hello world this is a heart \\u2764".
```

Then pass it to the apache's method.

```
String convertedStr = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
```

You need to have [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachecommonslangjar.htm) jar in your project for above method.

Hope this helps!